# Method contentsChanged in class JComboBox slow on Windows 10

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

Below is a sample *Swing* application that contains a `JComboBox` and a `JButton`. Pressing the button runs a SQL query that populates the model of the `JComboBox`. The query returns around 600 rows. My machine has 4 GB of RAM.

`JComboBox` implements interface `ListDataListener` and so it implements method `contentsChanged()`. Hence this method is invoked when the model is changed.

My investigations show that this method is very slow on Windows 10. Here is a table of results.

```
Java  8 (32 bit) on Windows  7 (32 bit)  < 0.5 seconds

Java  8 (64 bit) on Windows 10 (64 bit)    3.0 seconds

Java 11 (64 bit) on Windows 10 (64 bit)  > 1.5 seconds

Java  5 (32 bit) on Windows 10 (64 bit)  > 1.5 seconds
```

Needless to say, the fewer rows returned by the SQL query, the less time method `contentsChanged()` takes to complete.

Here is the code of my sample application.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SqlComb0 implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private JComboBox<Object>  combo;
    private JFrame  frame;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actnEvnt) {
        try {
            fetch();
        }
        catch (SQLException xSql) {
            xSql.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Fetch");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(button);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createComboPanel() {
        JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Initial"});
        comboPanel.add(combo);
        return comboPanel;
    }

    private void fetch() throws SQLException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("key", "val");
        String url = "jdbc:***";
        String sql = "select code, text "  +
                       "from table "       +
                      "where key = ?";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setInt(1, 0);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int code = rs.getInt(1);
                String description = rs.getString(2);
                String item = String.format("%04d %s", code, description);
                rows.add(item);
            }
            Object[] items = rows.toArray();
            DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items);
            combo.setModel(model);
        }
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("SqlComb0");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createComboPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SqlComb0());
    }
}
```

Perhaps someone has encountered this problem and has found a way to speed up the `contentsChanged()` method in `JComboBox` on Windows 10?

---

## EDIT

Thanks to *camickr*'s comment regarding the source of the data used to populate the `JComboBox` model, I discovered that there is a **big** difference in the time taken for the method `contentsChanged()` to complete when the *description* contains ASCII characters only than when it contains Hebrew characters.

So I guess the question now is: Why does Hebrew cause method `contentsChanged()` to run slower (on Windows 10)?

---

## EDIT 2

After more investigation, including profiling with [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), it looks like the bottle-neck is method `layoutCompoundLabelImpl()` in class `SwingUtilities` (if I understand the *VisualVM* output). Here is a screen capture of the *VisualVM* output.

1. Am I interpreting the output correctly? Is the bottle-neck method `layoutCompoundLabelImpl()`?
2. If I am interpreting the output correctly, can I do something to lower the time taken by this method?

[image: VisualVM screen capture]

Comment: I don't know how to speed up the method, but the database code should be run in a background thread, such as via a SwingWorker, and the model updated on the event thread. Your best solution may be to batch the updates to the model so that initially received data is displayed quickly

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels _the database code should be run in a background thread, such as via a SwingWorker_ Been there. Done that. Didn't help. My investigations show that ___all___ the database code executes ___very___ quickly. Like I wrote, the bottle neck is ___definitely___ the `contentsChanged()` method.

Comment: *all the database code executes very quickly.* - then forget about the database code in your [mre]. We don't have access to your database so we can't confirm/deny the statements you are making. *the bottle neck is definitely the contentsChanged() method* - so then create code to generate your 600 test rows and add them to the model. Then maybe someone will be able to test the code and verify your problem. I don't use Windows 10 so I can't compare.

Comment: @camickr I asked if someone has encountered this problem. Sounds like you haven't so that would mean the question is not relevant for you. _I don't use Windows 10_ Again, looks like this is a question you cannot answer since the problem only occurs for me with Windows 10. As seen in my results table, there is no problem on Windows 7. Is it a problem to create a database table with 600 rows? Or do you also not have access to a database? Nonetheless, how do you propose to replace the database? Would a CSV file suffice?

Comment: My comment was designed for you to learn how to ask a better question by knowing what is relevant to demonstrate the problem. Since the database is not the problem it should never have been mentioned in the question. We don't have time to read irrelevant information. *how do you propose to replace the database?* - you create a loop to generate 600 Integer objects. Again, your claim is that adding objects to the model is the issue, so where the data comes from is irrelevant. All that is important that you have 600 items to display.

Comment: @camickr See my edit to the question, regarding Hebrew in the `JComboBox` model. How do you propose I change the code of the sample program in order to supply a model that contains Hebrew? Should I provide a link to a text file? Should I add a loop in the code?

Comment: *there is a big difference ... when it contains Hebrew characters.* - that is the point of the [MRE], to keep the example as simple as possible to find problems like this. *... in order to supply a model that contains Hebrew* - I know nothing about Hebrew characters. What happens if you have a string of 5-10 Hebrew characters and then you concatenate this string with the Integer you generate in a loop? Is the problem any Hebrew character? The easier your code is to copy/paste/compile/test the more chance you will have that someone will look at your question.

Comment: Having said that, you have a very unique situation so I don't know if anybody will be able to answer the question because it seems like this is getting into the rendering of non ascii characters.

Comment: With the new information provided I did a quick search and found this: [The curious case of Hebrew rendering in Java swing](https://hackernoon.com/the-curious-case-of-hebrew-rendering-in-java-swing-2c656537c98b). I'm sure you won't like the solution, but at least it addresses your issue.

Comment: Note, is your Hebrew unique for each item, or is it the same with unique ascii text? If the Hebrew is the same, then maybe you could create a custom renderer. That is store the Hebrew and ascii as two properties in the item. Then you keep a HashMap of Hebrew text and it corresponding JLabel. In the render you then use a JPanel with two labels, one for the asci and one for the Hebrew. This way you only translate the Hebrew for the unique text?